# Calculate current flowing through each of the resistors in the following circuit:

Tags: current, resistors, ohms-law, circuits, calculation

[image: Circuit diagram]

I'm not sure how to go about this, but the answers are below

Comment: Where are you stuck? We don't answer homework questions without some evidence of effort. The answers given are sort-of correct.

Comment: This looks like a homework question, and we don't do homework on this site. If you specify exactly what you don't understand, I'm sure someone will help you. For a start, using Kirchhoff's Laws write down the 2 equations for the left and right hand loops letting current i1 and i2 flow through the 10 and 20 ohm resistors respectively. You now have 2 simultaneous equations in i1 and i2 you can solve with simple algebra.

Comment: `the answers are below` What is your question?

Comment: @AntonioDeAngelis - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However: (a) You made a suggested edit (which was wrongly approved - I have reversed that) which put an *answer* from you *as an update in the question*. That is never correct etiquette on Stack Exchange. (b) The question is currently [closed](/help/closed-questions) as it's a homework-type question and they get special treatment here - a solution attempt by the OP is *required*. So although I realise it can be frustrating when we have a solution, it cannot be posted as an answer on a closed question. Please answer non-closed questions :) TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a **hint** that simplifies your circuit in order to find the current through the 20 Ω resistor: -

[image]

- Do you understand the source transformation that I made?
- Do you know how to calculate the net value of parallel resistors?
- Can you then solve for \$I_{20}\$?

Of course you could solve it with superposition but it's easier this way IMHO.

- Once you have \$I_{20}\$ you can then reapply that current to your original circuit
- And calculate the voltage at the common node of the three resistors
  That then gives you \$I_{40}\$ quite automatically
- Once you have \$I_{20}\$ and \$I_{40}\$,  and \$I_{10}\$ is easily revealed

Comment: It was actually quite easy, I'm not an EE but for some reason, it's on my uni course, thanks for any help provided.

I realised I was overthinking a bit...